# Пропал InternalToponymInfo

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Хотел бы уточнить следующий вопрос. Вчера столкнулся с тем, что геокодер в ответе больше не возвращает поле InternalToponymInfo (расположение поля в ответе - yandexResponse.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[0].GeoObject.metaDataProperty.GeocoderMetaData.InternalToponymInfo).
При попытке откатиться на раннюю фиксированную версию выдает тот же результат - поля нет, хотя ранее, использовал именно его в коде.
Уточните пожалуйста, почему данное поле отсутствует в текущих ответах от Яндекса и, если его убрали, почему об этом не сказано в релизах?

Answer (score 1):

Это какое-то внутреннее служебное поле ответа. Судя по документации, оно никогда не являлось частью публичного API.

Недокументированные сущности, например, дебаговые параметры и служебные данные в ответе могут произвольно меняться. Не стоит завязываться на них в своих проектах.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Уточните пожалуйста, является ли yandexResponse.GeoObjectCollection.metaDataProperty.GeocoderResponseMetaData.Point частью API и можно ли заложиться на его стабильность и неизменность?

Comment: Вот тут описано с примерами, что API гарантирует в ответе: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/reference/response_structure-docpage/

Comment: Большое спасибо!